# Base Template is not loaded when state is changed in Angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-ui-router

I'm building a Web App using Angular-UI-Router to handle navigation at client side. 
The default landing page is "homepage" with URL: '/'. Based template is sent from nodejs server using express:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('blank.html', {root: './public/views/pages'});
});
```

Client side `app-routes.js`:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
 function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    // Redirect to '/' in case of unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    // Setup the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            abstract : true,
            // Note: abstract still needs a ui-view for its children
            // to populate
            template : '<ui-view/>'
        })
        .state('home.homepage', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/views/partials/homepage.html',
            controller: ''
        }).state('home.sign-in', {
            url: '/sign-in',
            templateUrl: '/views/partials/login.html',
            controller: 'AuthenticationCtrl'
        });
   $stateProvider.state('user', {
           abstract : true,
           url: '/user',
           templateUrl : '/views/pages/user-profile.html',
           template: '<ui-view/>',
           onEnter: function(){
             console.log("enter state");
           }
        }).state('user.products', {
           url: '/user/products',
           templateUrl: '/views/partials/products.html',
           controller: 'ProductCtrl'
        });
```

When enter `/`, template `blank.html` is loaded and `homepage.html` is replaced in `<div ui-view/>` tag. 
Go to `/sign-in` and login with user credentials successfully, set state to go to `user.products`

```
$scope.login = function (credentials) {
            Auth.signin(credentials).then(function (data) {
                Principle.setToken(data.data, $scope.remember_me);
                $state.go('user.products', {});
            }, function (res) {
                $scope.message = res.message;
                $state.go('home.sign-in', {});
            });
        }
```

The issue here is that based template `user-profile.html` never get loaded. It always displays `blank.html` template

Project structure:

```
---public     
       js
         +----app.js
         +----app-routes.js
       views
         +--pages
              +---blank.html
              +---user-profile.html
```